# Filter Flux<String> publisher by values from another Flux<String> publisher

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I want to filter **rangeFlux** by the values in the **filterFlux**. Is there any way how to achieve this without blocking in the line 2 with *toStream()*?

```java
        Flux<String> filterFlux = Flux.just("2", "3", "4", "5");
        List<String> collect = filterFlux.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        Flux<Integer> rangeFlux = Flux.range(1, 10);
        StepVerifier.create(rangeFlux.map(String::valueOf)
                .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(String s) {
                        return !collect.contains(s);
                    }
                }))
            .expectNext("1")
            .expectNext("6")
            .expectNext("7")
            .expectNext("8")
            .expectNext("9")
            .expectNext("10")
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this is a tricky one.

You could use the `filterWhen` function on `Flux` - it tests each value emitted by the given flux against a `Boolean` publisher.

`filterFlux` can be used with the `filterWhen` function as the source publisher for the filtering.

So to put that into code, it would look something like this:

```java
Flux<String> filterFlux = Flux
    .just("2", "3", "4", "5");

Flux<String> rangeFlux = Flux
    .range(1, 10)
    .map(String::valueOf);

Flux<String> filteredFlux = rangeFlux
    .filterWhen(s1 -> filterFlux.all(s2 -> !s1.equals(s2)));

StepVerifier
    .create(filteredFlux)
    .expectNext("1")
    .expectNext("6")
    .expectNext("7")
    .expectNext("8")
    .expectNext("9")
    .expectNext("10")
    .expectComplete()
    .verify();
```

**Edit**: Updated with suggestion from Patrick Hooijer

Comment: Good answer. However, There's something that could be added to improve the answer : Should we "share" or "cache" the `filterListMono` to avoid it being recomputed on each subscription (i.e each time we want to filter an element from `rangeFlux`) ? Also (but it is a detail) instead of collecting to a list, collecting to a set instead can speed the `contains` operation (if the number of filter element is big enough, I admit).

Comment: @cpigeon, thanks for the solution. I have tried that out in my project and it works

Comment: @amanin, thanks for the additional improvement suggestions. caching option is a must-have because in my project filterListMono is based on a DB call.

Comment: @amanin fair point on both counts! Though not fundamentally related to the original question, so I would prefer to keep the answer as it is. Set is easy enough to change to; Artyom, if you want to look at options for caching & replaying signals, have a look at Sinks, they are another great tool in the Reactor kit! Alternatively, the publishers themselves also have useful methods for this.

Comment: This answer can be improved further in case the filterFlux is a slow publisher: By keeping filterFlux a `Flux<String>`, you can replace the filterWhen with `.filterWhen(s1 -> filterFlux.all(s2 -> !s1.equals(s2))`. This way, filterFlux is cancelled once an equal element is found.

Comment: @PatrickHooijer Fair point! Updated answer.